# Issues with overriding methods in swift

Tags: swift

I am new in swift and getting some errors in following code:

```
class Player {
    var  name: String
    var score: Int

    func playerInfo()->(String, Int){
        return (name, score)
    }

    init(name:String, score:Int){
        self.name  = name
        self.score = score
    }
}

final class GoldPlayer : Player {
    var status: String
    init(name: String, score: Int, status: String) {
        self.status = "Gold"
        super.init(name: name, score: score)
    }
    func playerInfo() -> (String, Int, String) {
        return (name, score, status)

    }

}
```

Error is on line where I override `playerInfo() -> (String, Int, String)`
If I type `override` in front of method, I get error message `method does not override any methods from its superclass`. If I won't type `override`, I get error message when I call that method from a class instance, that says `ambiguous use of playerInfo()`. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not a swift coder, but what you're trying to do is "overloading" not "overriding"

Comment: @Coderchu It's not overloading either. The only difference between the functions is the return type. It should be called "hiding" or "shadowing".

Comment: @Sweeper Oh my mistake, I thought those data types were the param list. Really not a swift coder lol

Comment: @Sweeper This is, in fact, overloading.  Types are part of a method's signature in Swift and as such both are accessible.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in Tikhonov's answer you cannot override the method because they have different return types. So **remove the override keyword**.

The actual problem here is that the compiler is not able to determine which method you are trying to call. So you just need to specify the **type of the variable in which you will store the return value**.

```
let instance = GoldPlayer()

let x: (String, Int, String) = instance.playerInfo()
```

If you don't explicitly specify the type of the variable which stores the result of the function then you will get the error "Ambiguous use of playInfo" as compiler can only differentiate these two functions based on their return type and you didn't provide that info.

Answer (score 2):

Because compiler doesn't know what type would you like to use.

You can specify the type exactly

```
let goldPlayer = GoldPlayer(name: "Vasa", score: 33, status: "high")
let result: (String, Int, String)  = goldPlayer.playerInfo()
```

And you cannot use override keyword, because you functions have different signature. At first case  `func f()-> (String, Int)`, at second case `func f() -> (String, Int, String)`. You could use override if the second function has return type `(String, Int)`